# test for significant for more than 2x2 consistency table

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have some ratios like this:

```
TumorType Positive_Test Total
X 87 96
Y 112 124
Z 92 147
```

I want to test whether there is a significant difference in the column `Positive_Test` between each category under `TumorType` i.e. between X-Y, Y-Z and X-Z as well as overall X-Y-Z. I did a `chi-square test` to get an overall p-value between X-Y-Z. However, I wanted to know if there is a test where I can get p-values for each of the comparisons as well showing significant differences between the three rows.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks!

Comment: In your title do you intend [*contingency table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) rather than "consistency table"? If yes, please edit your title to correct it. If no, please define "consistency table" in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my analysis. I think it is best to start by looking at all of the data.

First, put the data into a *contingency* table, with
columns 'Positive' and 'Negative'.

```
DTA = matrix(c(87,96-87, 112,124-112, 92,147-92), byrow=T, nrow=3)

DTA
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   87    9
[2,]  112   12
[3,]   92   55
```

Check to see that the row sums add to the proper totals; they do:

```
rowSums(DTA)
[1]  96 124 147
```

Notice that overall there are many more positive tests than negative ones:

```
colSums(DTA)
[1] 291  76
```

Perform a chi-squared test for homogeneity of 'Test' across 'Type', obtaining
a highly significant result, rejecting the null hypothesis that each tumor type is equally likely to show positive results. OK, something interesting is going on. We should try to understand where the differences are.

```
out = chisq.test(DTA); out

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 41.686, df = 2, p-value = 8.872e-10
```

Check that expected values all exceed 5. They do.

```
out$exp
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  76.11989 19.88011
[2,]  98.32153 25.67847
[3,] 116.55858 30.44142
```

Look for patterns in Pearson residuals, noting that the last row
seems different from the others. Mainly the third tumor type seems to have shown
proportionalley fewer positive tests than did the other two tumor types. 
The observed counts for tumor Z are 92 and 55, while expected counts are about 116.6 and 30.4: quite a discrepancy. [Pearson residuals
with absolute values much greater than 2 are worthy of notice.]

```
out$resi
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  1.247051 -2.440191
[2,]  1.379473 -2.699312
[3,] -2.274737  4.451136
```

Test to see if Type Z differs from Type Y; Yes, highly significant difference:

```
chisq.test(DTA[2:3,])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  DTA[2:3, ]
X-squared = 26.336, df = 1, p-value = 2.869e-07
```

Test to see if Type Z differs from Type X; Yes, highly significant difference:

```
chisq.test(DTA[c(1,3),])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  DTA[c(1, 3), ]
X-squared = 22.112, df = 1, p-value = 2.572e-06
```

Test to see if Types X and Y differ (from residuals, this seems unlikely, but check anyway); No, not even close to significant:

```
chisq.test(DTA[1:2,])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  DTA[1:2, ]
X-squared = 9.7749e-30, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

Although we have done three 'post hoc' tests, there seems no reason to 
use Bonferroni significance levels, or otherwise guard against 'false
discovery', because the two differences confirmed are very highly significant with
very small P-values.

If you think it would make it easier to explain your findings to others,
you could do binomial tests or Fisher Exact Tests for the post hoc
comparisons involving $2 \times 2$ sub-tables, but I do not see a need for
those procedures.

*Addendum:*  Here is a [barplot](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/) of the results: `DTA` needs to be transposed
for this format.

```
farb=c("maroon","green3");  hdr="Tumor Types by Test Result"
barplot(t(DTA), main=hdr, col=farb, ylab="Counts", beside=T, names=c("X","Y","Z"))
legend("topright", c("Positive","Negative"), bty="n", fill=farb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit mislabled, because you have already conducted a test for a table that is larger than a 2x2 table. I suppose what you want to do is to test for differences between rows. i.e. you want to know whether there is a difference between X and Y across tumour type and positive test. This can also be accomplished with a chi-square test. In R this can be run without any additional packages in the following way - the example compares z and y:

```
m<-as.table(rbind(c(92,147),c(112,124)))
dimnames(m)<-list(condition=c("z","y"),test=c("tumourtype","positivetest"))

chisq.test(m)
```

If you want to test proportions across conditions, the R function prop.test can be used to do this

Comment: Yes, so basically I wanted to know if there is a test that can be done once to get individual p-values but I guess I can also do a chi-square for each comparison.

Comment: This is kind of hard to answer, because I am not sure what your data represent. Do the numbers in positive test reflect a subgroup of those in tumour type? i.e. are you looking at how many tested positive and how many didn't for each tumourtype? You could potentially run this as a logistic regression and interpret estimates for each group. However, this would not give you an x vs y vs z comparison. You would have one group as a baseline and then the values associated with the other groups would be in reference to it.

Comment: Yes - basically out of the Total (3rd column), Positive is how many were tested positive for that tumor type (column 1)

Comment: Ah, then you will need to reformat your data in the way @BruceET refers to below. Namely, the data in the third column should be all the values in the first column subtracted from the total. Otherwise, you are double counting.