# test of two proportions

Tags: self-study, t-test, chi-squared-test

Apologies for an elementary question - I am trying to understand the solution to the following problem:

> *"Suppose interviews were conducted at two different shopping centers. This two sample t-test between percents could be used to determine if
>   the responses from the two shopping centers were different. The
>   research question is: Is there a significant difference between
>   shopping centers A and B with respect to the percent that say they
>   would buy product X? The null hypothesis is: There is no significant
>   difference between shopping centers A and B with respect to the
>   percent of people that say they would buy product X. A two-tailed
>   probability will be used because the hypothesis does not state the
>   direction of the difference. The results of the survey were: 89 people
>   were interviewed as shopping center A and 57 of them (64.0%) said they
>   would buy product X. 92 people were interviewed as shopping center B
>   and 51 of them (55.4%) said they would buy product X."*

This is an example given at https://www.statpac.com/statistics-calculator/percents.htm

And they go on to give an answer:

> *"t-value = 1.179 Degrees of freedom = 179 Two-tailed probability = .240"*

Could someone help me understand how the answers are obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you have done in the Online Calculator, but it seems to me
that this is a test to see if proportions of buyers in the two shopping
centers are the same. I don't see how it would be appropriate to do a
two-sample t test here. (However, a P-value around 0.24 does seem roughly correct.)

It seems as if this question may need a 'self-study' tag, so to get you
started on a useful track, I will show results from a couple of statistical
software packages, and a formula from a standard textbook. Methods for
this test differ slightly among various texts and software packages, a
textbook you have may give a slightly different answer.

In Minitab 17 the test looks like this:

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X   N  Sample p
1       57  89  0.640449
2       51  92  0.554348


Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0861016
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0562171, 0.228420)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 1.19  P-Value = 0.236
```

Also, here is the output from R statistical software (without continuity correction):

```
prop.test(c(57,51), c(89,92), corr=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(57, 51) out of c(89, 92)
X-squared = 1.3936, df = 1, p-value = 0.2378
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.05621706  0.22842029
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.6404494 0.5543478
```

A formula for the test statistic in Ott & Longnecker, 5e, Chapter 10
is as follows:

With estimates $\hat p_a = 0.640, \hat p_b = 0.554,$ the normally
distributed test statistic is
$ Z = \frac{\hat p_a - \hat p_b}{\text{SE}},$ where
$\text{SE}^2 = \frac{\hat p_a(1-\hat p_a)}{89} + \frac{\hat p_b(1-\hat p_b)}{92}.$

The first term in $\text{SE}^2$ is an estimate of $Var(\hat p_a)$
and the second term is an estimate of $Var(\hat p_b).$

The approach used here involves a normal approximation to the difference
of two binomial proportions. Sample sizes are large enough and estimates
are far enough from 0 and 1 that the normal approximation should work quite well.

If you need further help with this, please edit some of your work based
on what I have shown into your question, and explain your difficulty.
Then perhaps someone will provide a clarification.

Comment: Thank you @BruceET. Being a newbie, my upvote isn't counted. The answers I quoted were provided by the site - not something I calculated. I take from you that the site is incorrect in applying t-test in this case. If it were the right test to apply, how would they have got the answers? Given that they got the test incorrect, perhaps the answers too are?

Comment: To an extent (certainly not invariably), the menu systems in established software such as Minitab, Stata, SPSS may offer a useful guide what procedure to use. Even so, best to know what you're doing before engaging software. // Sites that pop up on the Internet are considerably less reliable. // The correct analysis uses an approx of the normal distribution to functions of binomial random variables. I don't know what proc the online your 'Calculator' used. Note that the t dist'n with 179 DF is nearly normal, so hardly surprising that _some_ calc with your data produced close to right answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you are going to ask more questions here it is probably worthwhile to 'take the tour' of the site. No worries about up-voting for now. That will come soon. I think already you can click to 'Accept' and answer when you feel you've gotten what you need from the various answers and comments. (That will take your post off our list of unanswered questions.)

Comment: Thanks @BruceET. Could I oblige you with another question, please. I have some data related to exams: same course, two successive years. I have the counts of students who got A, B, C, and F in both years. Population size is different. The second exam was done in a somewhat different environment. What statistical test should I consider using if my null hypothesis is to say that the new environment made no difference? As you probably guessed, I am true newbie and scoring through several sources to learn some of the very basics.

Comment: I think I get the idea. Provided students are different in the two years, you can make a $4 \times 2$ table of counts: Rows (A, B, C, F), Columns (Yr1, Yr2). Do a chi-squared test for homogeneity of grade proportions across years. Same procedure as test of independence. Look at [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364605/test-for-significant-for-more-than-2x2-consistency-table/364611#364611) for some R code and hints for interpretation. Post table as new question if you have trouble with interpretation, and someone will probably help with that.